# same PDF file gets downloaded repeatedly everytime webview loads in Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

In Titanium Appceleartor i tried to open PDF files(from webview) in web browser. I have used openURL property.
First i have created a webview with a label.On clicking that label,i tried to load another webview which contains "PDF" file.
    PDF file is getting openend in browser, but the problem is whenever the inner webview gets loaded, that pdf file is downloaded even if it is already available in device's "Download" folder.
    How to restrict downloading the pdf file,if it is already present in "downloads" folder & open it from cache?

My code;

```
var outerWebView = Ti.UI.createView({});

var pdfLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : 'click here to open pdf docx',
});

outerWebView.add(pdfLabel);

pdfLabel.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var innerwebview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        top : 0,left : 10,
    });
    outerWebView.add(innerwebview);

    Ti.Platform.openURL(myURL);
});
```

Comment: You may have to create a module to solve this problem. I don't think you can do this through the Titanium API

Comment: yeah. This is Titanium 3.1.3 issue & i wrote an intent method to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for android try cacheMode property for web view (Titanium.UI.Android.WEBVIEW_LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK)